# Realm delete all except one table

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-java

This is **Realm Java** so I'm doing

```
realm.beginTransaction();
realm.deleteAll();
realm.commitTransaction();
```

I have 20 or so `Realm` classes. **I only want to keep one**.

Instead of doing

```
realm.beginTransaction();
  realm.delete(Table1.class);
  realm.delete(Table2.class);
  realm.delete(Table3.class);
  ...
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Is there a way to delete all tables except one?

"deleteAll.except(Table12.class)" etc?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure!

```
final RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = realm.getConfiguration();
r.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
    for(Class<? extends RealmModel> clazz : realmConfiguration.getRealmObjectClasses()) {
        if(clazz != Table12.class) {
            realm.delete(clazz);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For posterity here's the code with minor fixes: 

realm.executeTransaction((realm) -> {
            for(Class<? extends RealmModel> clazz : realmConfiguration.getRealmObjectClasses()) {
                if(clazz != Table12.class) {
                    realm.delete(clazz);
                }
            }
        });

Comment: I am logging `getRealmObjectClasses.size` before and after the for loop, surprisingly I get same number. Then I tried finding result of a realm class before and after deleting it, here I see 0 result after deleting which is expected but how those object classes are not getting cleared ???

Comment: `getRealmObjectClasses` returns the number of classes within the Realm schema, and clearing all rows (`realm.delete(clazz)`) does NOT remove them from the schema. If you do `realm.where(clazz).count()` then it will give you `0` however.